# Unable to parse date string using mutliple formats

Tags: c#, datetime

I'll get straight into it, one of my pet peeves is working with `DateTime` it's more than likely my lack of understanding when it comes to `cultures` `timezones` and globalization.

Within my App, that is used on international level, I'm trying to figure out the best approach to build a function that will handle all formats irrespective of passed in format.

I suppose at the moment I'm not entirely sure, why I have a specific format that will not parse into a date, which is passed in via a client.

This is all in test for the time being, but never the less a pain in the beep...

At the moment, I'm trying to convert `en_gb` dates and also a `standard ISO format` Snippet of code attached.

```
string[] formats = {
    "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
    "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt",
    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss",
    "d/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
    "d/M/yyyy hh tt",
    "d/M/yyyy h:mm",
    "d/M/yyyy h:mm",
    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", 
    "dd/m/yyyy hh:mm",
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss UTC"
};

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(val, formats, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out dt))
{
    return dt;
}
```

So if I may ask, why does `13/06/2017  10:25:00 UTC` parse but `27/06/2017  16:11:00 UTC` fails (returns false).

I feel I may have been staring at this for too long.

Really appreciate a nudge in the right direction...

Comment: You might be better off to use a dedicated library, such as NodaTime, instead of trying to reimplement all that logic by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're matching on the time is using `h` or `hh` which is 12 hour clock time (ie it accepts 1-12 or 01-12). If you were to add `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC"` to your format list then this would then be able to match `27/06/2017  16:11:00 UTC`. In general I suspect anything without the `tt` specifier probably want to have `H`/`HH` rather than `h`/`hh` though I leave it to you to decide for sure what you want.

Docs found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-h-custom-format-specifier

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate that. It turned out, I had been staring at it too long... Something I'd neglected. Thumbs up.

Comment: Yup. Easy mistake. I've just noticed you also do have a lowercase `m` in a month position in `dd/m/yyyy hh:mm` (that's the one I always used to get wrong).

Comment: Thank you, I did miss that too. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

```
static void FormatDate(string strInputDateTimeValue)
        {
            int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, milliSeconds = 0, dateTimeKind = 0;
            List<string> lstSplittedInputDateTime = (from data in strInputDateTimeValue.Split(' ').ToList() where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) select data).ToList();
            if (lstSplittedInputDateTime != null)
            {
                string strDate = lstSplittedInputDateTime[0];//Fetching Only Date Part: Considering date format will be mm/DD/yyyy
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strDate))
                {
                    month = Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Split('/').ToList()[1]);//Fetch Month
                    day = Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Split('/').ToList()[0]);//Fetch Day
                    year = Convert.ToInt32(strDate.Split('/').ToList()[2]);//Fetch Year
                }
                string strTime = lstSplittedInputDateTime[1];//Fetching Only Time Part
                if (strTime != null)
                {
                    hours = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Split(':').ToList()[0]);//Fetch Hours
                    minutes = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Split(':').ToList()[1]);//Fetch Minutes
                    seconds = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Split(':').ToList()[2]);//Fetch Seconds
                    milliSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(strTime.Split(':').ToList()[3]);//Fetch MilliSeconds
                }
                string strDateTimeKind = lstSplittedInputDateTime[2];//Fetching DateTimeKind
                if (strDateTimeKind != null)
                {
                    if (strDateTimeKind.ToLower() == "utc")
                        dateTimeKind = (int)System.DateTimeKind.Utc;
                    else if (strDateTimeKind.ToLower() == "Local")
                        dateTimeKind = (int)System.DateTimeKind.Local;
                    else
                        dateTimeKind = (int)System.DateTimeKind.Utc;
                }
            }
            DateTime dtFormattedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, (DateTimeKind)dateTimeKind);
            Console.WriteLine("Local: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtFormattedDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("UTC: {0}", TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dtFormattedDate, TimeZoneInfo.Utc).ToString());
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            FormatDate("27/06/2017  16:11:00 UTC");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Whilst I fully appreciate your contribution, I'm very much against the overuse of conditionals. I feel your answer maybe a little overkill for what I need. Never the less, thanks for your time.